# ReSharper - Can I turn off suggestions for “Invert if” and similar?

Tags: resharper

So for the last weeks I am forced to use ReSharper at work. Generally a great tool, lots of great refactoring options. But it has always something to say. On every single line...

The system I work on is quite big and old, and sometimes I am to have make some minor changes on some old code (which was written before any guidelines existed), and I am told to not refactor the whole thing. Then ReSharper colours the whole thing, because naming is wrong, if-statements can be simplified and more. This basically just distracts me form my work.

So can I turn off suggestions to "Invert if-statement" or similar things?

Alternatively, can I make it sum-up all suggestions into a tool-bar like the error list or callstack? (and keep my working screen clean from colouring and suggestions)

Comment: I kind of liked the invert-if but it wasn't popular in a code review today so I will have to change those back. Other developers mentioned that it made the code more complicated and less readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Invert if-statement' and the likes are called Context Actions. They can be turned on and off under:

> ReSharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> Context Actions

Similar to those the suggestions can be configured under:

> ReSharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Inspection Serverity.

Though the severity can also be changed using the Alt + Enter menu.

Comment: Just to add - everything is configurable. You can disable context actions, change the severity of the inspection "squigglies" - change to suggestion, hint or even hide them completely. And you can also change the naming standards. With a bit of configuration, it can match how you work.